# Prove that IK, AC, BD are concurrent.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, tangent-line, geometric-transformation

> Given a circle (O, R) with diameter AB. Point M on (O), A, B are not coincident. Two lines through O and perpendicular to AM, BM intersects the tangent of (O) through M at C, D, respectively. OC intersects AM at I, OD intersects BM at K. Prove that IK, AD, BC are concurrent.

[image: The figure]

**Attempts:** I tried drawing an altitude through M of triangle ABC, intersecting IK at some point but still stuck on proving that it is the midpoint of that altitude. AC, BD are tangents of (O) and I, K are midpoints of AM, BM respectively has been proved.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Show your attempts.

Comment: This is a direct consequence of Pappus' theorem, applied for lines $AOB$ and $CDM$.

Comment: Is analytical geometry allowed?

Comment: Analytical geometry is not allowed. Also, Pappus' theorem is way too advanced for this problem, and I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: Take this with a **large** grain of salt, given that I am generally ignorant of Geometry.  "Also, Pappus' theorem is way too advanced for this problem" Sometimes, in a case like this, if all else fails, you can (for example) examine the proof to Pappus' theorem and see if you can "*lift out some of the analysis*" and use it to reverse-engineer a simple proof to your query.

Comment: Use Aqua's elegant and simple solution from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3889283/problem-with-right-angle-triangle-circumscribed-circle-tangent-and-the-half-of as a starting point. It gives you the key part of yur solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $IK$ intersects $AD$ at $S$. Then homothety at $S$ which takes $A$ to $D$ takes $I$ to $K$. If we prove that it takes also $C$ to $B$ then we are done.

Now $CA =CM$ so the line $CA$ is also tangent to (semi) cricle at $A$ and thus $CA\bot AB$. The same way we have $BD\bot AB$, so $CA||BD$. But this now means that $C$ goes to $B$ and we are done.