# Problem with right angle triangle, circumscribed circle, tangent and the half of its height

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-transformation, homothety

(An interesting problem inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888494/prove-that-ik-ac-bd-are-concurrent) one but still different. And, no, I'm not looking for your help to solve a detail here in order to provide a full solution elsewhere. I'll stop here).

> A right-angled triangle ABM is given ($\angle M = 90^\circ)$. A tangent $t$ is drawn at point $M$ to the circumscribed circle with center $O$. Perpendicular bisector $OE$ of side $AM$ meets tangent $t$ at point $D$. Prove that line $DB$ cuts triangle height $MH$ in half ($CM=CH$)

[image]

Ok, one way to solve this is to use analytical geometry. It's doable but tedious. More ellegant way is to solve the problem by using complex geometry and I will demonstrate that solution here:

We'll take circumscribed circle to be unit circle. Let's assign the following complex numbers to various points: $z_M=z,z_0=0,z_A=-1,z_B=1$. It's a well know formula that:

$$z_D=\frac{2z_Mz_A}{z_M+z_A}=\frac{-2z}{z-1}$$

Also notice that:

$$Re(C)=Re(M)=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$$

$$Im(C)=\frac12 Im(M)=\frac12\frac1{2i}(z-\bar{z})$$

$$z_C=Re(C)+i\cdot Im(C)=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}+\frac14(z-\bar{z})=\frac 14(3z+\bar z)$$

The last thing we have to prove is that points $D,C,B$ are colinear which is true if:

$$z_D-z_B=k(z_C-z_B)$$

...for some real $k$. In other words:

$$\frac{-2z}{z-1}-1=k(\frac 14(3z+\bar z)-1)\iff$$

$$\frac{-2z-(z-1)}{z-1}=\frac{k}{4}(3z+\bar z-4)\iff$$

$$\frac{-3z+1}{z-1}\frac{\bar z-1}{\bar z-1}=\frac{k}{4}(3z+\bar z-4)\iff$$

$$\frac{-3z+1}{z-1}\frac{\bar z-1}{\bar z-1}=\frac{k}{4}(3z+\bar z-4)\iff$$

$$\frac{3z+\bar z-4}{l}=\frac{k}{4}(3z+\bar z-4)\iff$$

$$k=\frac4l, \quad l=(z-1)(\bar z - 1)\in R$$

**Question:** I think we can prove this with Euclid too, without complex or any other numbers. Can someone come up with one such solution?

Comment: I assume OE is a segment from the center of the circle to the midpoint of AM. That's not a median.

Comment: @AmeetSharma Right, +1! I have replaced "median" with "perpendicular bisector"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: [image]

- $BEF \sim BAD$ so $${a\over x} = {t\over z+t} = {y\over x+y}\implies a = {xy\over x+y}$$
- $BGD\sim FCD$ so $${b\over y} = {x\over x+y}\implies b = {yx\over x+y}$$

Comment: "Evo ovako" :) Serbia speaking?

Comment: Thank you for the clean and simple solution!

Answer (score 4):

extend $BM$ until it meets the  line $AD$ at $X$ since $\angle AMX=90$
$AD$ is  $\frac{AX} {2}$  by homothety  $CH$ is $\frac{MH} {2}$

Comment: +1. Good answer!

Comment: Yes, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AM=b$ and $BM=a$.

Thus, $$CH=HB\tan\measuredangle CBH=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cdot\tan\measuredangle DBA=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cdot\frac{DA}{AB}=$$
$$=\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}\cdot\frac{b}{2\cos\measuredangle DAE}=\frac{a^2b}{2(a^2+b^2)\cos\measuredangle ABM}=\frac{a^2b}{2(a^2+b^2)\cdot\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}=$$
$$=\frac{ab}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{1}{2}MH.$$